# serving TRAC on windows IIS using isapi_wsgi

Tags: windows, iis, trac, isapi-wsgi

any way to serve TRAC on windows IIS using isapi_wsgi ?

The isapi_wsgi adapter is considered stable. It has been used to deploy many wsgi compliant Python web applications and frameworks including Django, TurboGears, Mercurial and Trac.

http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/w/list

on this page there's some wikis on serving mercurial, but none for TRAC.

any detailed way to serve TRAC on windows IIS using isapi_wsgi ?

Answer (score 0):

it's almost the same step as mercurial, see here:

http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2010/04/08/Setting-up-Mercurial-server-in-IIS7-using-a-ISAPI-module.aspx
Setting up Mercurial server in IIS7 using a ISAPI module